# jQuery add class onclick

Tags: jquery, class, onclick, footer

Hi am currently using the code below for an expandable footer on my site.

I would like to adapt it so that when the link class '.toggle' is clicked it will add a class called '.is-open' to the element so far the code does this but then additionally I would like the code to add the class '.is-open' to another class called '.footercontrol'

```
$(".footer, .toggle:not(:first-child)").hide();

$(".toggle").click(function(e) {

e.preventDefault();

if ( $(this).hasClass("is-open") ){
    $(this).removeClass("is-open").nextAll(".footer, .toggle:not(:first-         child)").slideUp(500).removeClass("is-open");
    return;
}


$(this).toggleClass("is-open");
$(this).next(".footer").slideToggle(500).next(".toggle").slideToggle(500);

$("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: $(document).height()
}, 500);

});
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

managed to sort it myself in the end thanks to both your help, I simply amended the existing code and added another class to the existing events like so:

```
$(".footer, .toggle:not(:first-child)").hide();

$(".toggle, .footercontrol").click(function(e) {

e.preventDefault();

if ( $(this).hasClass("is-open") ){
    $(this).removeClass("is-open").nextAll(".footer, .toggle:not(:first-child),   .footercontrol").slideUp(500).removeClass("is-open");
    return;
}

$(this).toggleClass("is-open");
$(this).next(".footer").slideToggle(500).next(".toggle").slideToggle(500);

$("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: $(document).height()
}, 500);


});
```

and it seems to work perfectly, if I knew more about jQuery I probably would have thought to attempt that sooner. But thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

> I would like the code to add the class '.is-open' to another class
>   called '.footercontrol'

so you want this:

```
$(".footercontrol").addClass("is-open");
```

if I understood you correctly?

and if you have only one element that has this class, then you should consider using id instead of class. in practice nothing changes though.

### Edit:

if you also want it to be removed on second click, toggleClass seems to be doing it, though I never used it. I usually do it like this:

```
$( ".footercontrol" ).each(function( index ) {
 if($(this).hasClass("is-open"))
 {
  $(this).removeClass("is-open");
 }
 else
 {
  $(this).addClass("is-open");
 }
});
```

of course you can replace `$(this)` with `$(".footercontrol")` and make it a single call, instead of a `.each` loop, since you are dealing with only one element.

Comment: Oops sorry what I meant was that the 'is-open' class would toggle on both '.toggle' and '.footercontrol' with only one click. The code you've give me works perfectly at adding the class but I would like it to be removed again on a second click. Sorry for not being clearer!

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to add

```
$('.footercontrol').toggleClass('is-open');
```

within that function and have it work as intended.

e.g.

```
$(this).toggleClass("is-open");
$('.footercontrol').toggleClass('is-open');
$(this).next(".footer").slideToggle(500).next(".toggle").slideToggle(500);

$("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: $(document).height()
}, 500);
```